# use same form for user add and update Angular5

Tags: angular5

i am learning angular can someone please help me on following :

I have one form which save user (i call api on this submit click). i need to use same form for update user , for that i took two buttons i show "submit" button if user is new (i managethis new and old user from ge api call in OnInit()) and another button is "update" button, i show and hide this buttons depending on Get api call for user in onInit().

form demo code :

> ```
> <form class="form-area" (ngSubmit)="ngSubmit(applicant)" name="applicantForm" #applicantForm="ngForm" ngNativeValidate>
>
> <div> some fileds</div>
>
> <div class="row" style="content:center">
>       <div class="col-md-12">
>         <div class="form-row">
>           <div class="form-group">
>             <button *ngIf="submitStatus" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" [disabled]="!applicantForm.form.valid">
>               <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
>               <button *ngIf="updateStatus"  type="submit" class="btn btn-info" [disabled]="!applicantForm.form.valid">
>                 <i class="fa fa-send-o"></i>&nbsp;Update</button>  
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </form>
> ```

question : 
i call (ngSubmit)="ngSubmit(applicant)" method on submit button call to save user, but i confused in how i differentiate this both operation to call ngSubmit(applicant).

i need to perform both operation in single function call from controller.
thanks

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question. What do you want to do differently depending on whether the user is new or old?

Comment: When user first time submit the form I need to call post API on sumbit button .. and when user comes for second time and later i need to call update API ...I use same form for that ... On oninit() I call get user () API if which return user I hide the submit button and show update button if getuser() null I hide update button and show submit button , the problem is that ..how should I use the same ngsumbit() to perform this both different operations ?

Comment: You can modify your `ngsumbit` function to perform two different things, based on the same condition you use to show/hide the buttons

Comment: can you please create plunker on this ?

Comment: @BhagvatLande Can you please share your complete code .ts and .html So that it would be easier to understand what you are trying to do ?